# Assuming $u<0$, $\int_0^a v dx =0$, $|v|\le\varepsilon$, we can say that $\int_0^a u(x) v(x) \, dx \le 0$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functional-analysis, analysis

Let $a>0$ be fixed. Let $u, v$ two continuous, non-constant real valued functions such that:

1. $u<0$;
2. $\displaystyle\int_0^T v dx =0$;
3. there exists $\varepsilon>0$ small such that $|v|\le\varepsilon$.

I am trying to understand if those three conditions imply necessarily that
$$\int_0^a u(x) v(x) \, dx \le 0.$$

The only thing I have deduced so far is that as 2. holds and $v$ is continuous, thus necessarily $v$ changes its sign in $[0, a]$. Also, if 1. holds, then it is $\displaystyle\int_0^a u(x) dx <0$.

Nonetheless, I do not know how to proceed with the proof.

Could someone please help me in proving that? If it is false, could you please tell under what additional assumptions that integral il negative?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: (1) implies (2), doesn't it?

Comment: @MartinR, yes that's true. I think I can remove it.

Comment: What is T exactly？

Comment: $u(x) = -x$ and $v(x) = \sin(x)$ on $[0, 2\pi]$ is a counterexample.

Comment: @MartinR thank you for the counterexample. Could you please help me to understand under what additional assumptions that integral il negative?

Comment: What kind of conditions are you looking for? – For any  function $v$ with $\int v = 0$ you can choose $u = v - C$ with a sufficiently large constant $C$ to make it negative. Then $\int uv = \int v^2 > 0$.

Comment: @MartinR I am looking for a condition which makes $u$ independent on $v$ (I mean not like $u=v-C$). Actually I didn't understand your example since I need the integral to be negative and not positive.

Comment: Yes, I wanted to demonstrate that this is not possible in general. For any such function $v$ there is a negative function $u$ such that  $\int uv$ is positive.

Comment: @MartinR, thank you. Even if there exists $\varepsilon>0$ such that $|v|\le\varepsilon$? It was a required assumption in my question. I missed it, I am going to edit it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First a simple counter-example, then a proof that for every such $v$ we can find a counter-example $u$.

$\rhd$ I don't think this is true. Let's take $u : x \mapsto -x^2-1$, $v: x \mapsto b\times \left(\dfrac{T}{2}-x\right)$ with $b$ small enough such that $|v| < \varepsilon$. We have

1. $u < 0$ on $[0,T]$ ;
2. $|v| < \varepsilon$ ;
3. $\displaystyle\int_0^T v(x) dx = T\times \dfrac{T}{2}-\dfrac{T^2}{2}=0$.

But
$$\begin{array}{lll}
\displaystyle\int_0^T u(x)v(x) dx &=&\displaystyle \int_0^T x^3 - \dfrac{T}{2}x^2 dx \\
&=& \left[\dfrac{x^4}{4} - \dfrac{T}{6}x^3\right]_0^T \\
&=&\dfrac{T^4}{4}-\dfrac{T^4}{6}\\
&=&\dfrac{T^4}{12} >0.
\end{array}$$

Thre main problem is that $u$ can be bigger (in absolute value) when $v$ is negative than when $v$ is positive. Hence the positive contribution for $uv$ to the integral (i.e. when $v<0$) is bigger than its negative contribution (i.e. when $v>0$). Let's follow this idea to build a general counter-example.

$\rhd$ For a given $v$ satisfying the hypothesis, if $v$ is not everywhere equal to $0$, we can find $x_1$ and $x_2$ such that $v(x_1)>0$ and $v(x_2)<0$. As $v$ is continuous, we can find some neighborhhood $[a,b]$ of $x_2$ such that $v <0$ on $[a,b]$.

Let's take $\eta >0$ a constant to be defined later. Define $u$ as the continous function defined :

- $u$ is $-\eta$ on $[0,a]$ ;
- $u$ is the affine fonction going from $0$ to $-1$ on $[a,\frac{a+b}{2}]$
- $u$ is the affine fonction going from $-1$ to $0$ on $[\frac{a+b}{2},b]$
- $u$ is $-\eta$ on $[b,T]$.

Mainly, $u$ has a "big" negative peak on the interval $[a,b]$ and is very close to $0$ everywhere else. Then

$$\begin{array}{lll}
\displaystyle\int_0^T uv &=& \displaystyle\int_0^a uv +\displaystyle\int_a^b uv +\displaystyle\int_b^T uv \\
\end{array}$$
Note that $\displaystyle\int_a^b uv$ is a positive number (as $u$ and $v$ are strictly negative on $[a,b]$). Let's choose $\eta$ smmall enough such that
$$\eta \left(\displaystyle\int_0^a |v| + \displaystyle\int_b^T |v|\right) < \displaystyle\int_a^b uv.$$
Then we have
$$\begin{array}{lll}
\left|\displaystyle\int_0^a uv +\displaystyle\int_b^T uv \right| &\leq &\displaystyle\int_0^a |uv| +\displaystyle\int_b^T |uv| \\
&\leq &\displaystyle\int_0^a \eta|v| +\displaystyle\int_b^T \eta |v| \\
&\leq &\eta \left(\displaystyle\int_0^a |v| + \displaystyle\int_b^T |v|\right) \\
& < & \displaystyle\int_a^b uv.
\end{array}$$
Therefore $\displaystyle\int_a^b uv > -\left(\displaystyle\int_0^a uv +\displaystyle\int_b^T uv\right)$
$$\displaystyle\int_0^T uv = \displaystyle\int_0^a uv +\displaystyle\int_a^b uv +\displaystyle\int_b^T uv >0.$$